# phpStorm adding custom code completion

Tags: phpstorm, laravel, laravel-blade

I was hoping to add some custom auto-completion to phpStorm for Laravel Blade views, but I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation

Specifically, I want it to append the section closing when I type @section('secName').

So, typing

```
@section('mySection')
```

phpStorm would auto-append

```
@stop
```

Much like when you type

```
<p>
```

you end up with

```
<p></p>
```

I didn't see it [in the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/basic-code-completion-completing-names-and-keywords.html).  I know about Live Templates, but that's not exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not yet supported by PhpStorm.

Although, there is a [ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14172) requesting this functionaity in the PhpStorm bugtracker, you can vote for the issue to get it higher on the list.

Comment: AH, okay, glad I'm not just crazy and couldn't find it in the menus.

Edit:  Although this is specific support for Laravel, I just want to be able to add my own custom completion definitions.

Comment: @NickBrown seems like your question is answered, please mark it 'answered'

Answer (score 1):

you can create new Live Template on phpStorm! with Applicable is "Everywhere"

```
@section('$CONTENT$')
    $END$
@stop
```